Web service calls fail after upgrading Java 8 to 17
I have recently upgraded my application from Java 8 to Java 17 but started seeing below error wherever web service is being called-
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

I found that jdk 8 used to provide some additional dependencies which jdk17 doesn't provide anymore so we need to add them externally. I tried adding them but got into a rabbit hole and ended up with some other errors. I tried adding below dependency one after one to fix the runtime errors:
com.sun.xml.ws:policy:2.4  
com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.2.10
com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:1.5.3
org.jvnet.staxes:stax-ex:1.7.6

I am still clueless what's the main reason and what's missing part here. Can someone pls suggest?

I think you are missing 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind' and ''com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:3.0.2'

I have 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind'. I ended up adding more dependencies as follows to make it work -
javax.jws-api,
saaj-impl,
gmbal-api-only

Great. Can you answer your own question and mark it as the answer so it helps others?
